# ParseObject.save() throws IllegalArgumentException (Can't save a user that is not authenticated) WHY?

Tags: android, parse-platform, save

I have a Table in db, we can call it "A" with just 2 columns:

```
user (Pointer _User)
b (Pointer "B") (where "B" is another table in my db)
```

the code is:

```
    a.put("b", b);
    a.put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    a.save(); //I manage my threading
```

on a.save() the IllegalArgumentException in the title is thrown, please someone can explain me why? In the "B" table there's a column pointing another _User, I hope the problem doesn't depend on this!!!

this is the logcat output:

[image: logcat output]

Comment: Having the same problem. I can create one object with a field pointing to other user and save it for the first time. However, later on,  I cannot update that object.

Comment: Hey, did you finally got a solution to this problem ?

Comment: My problem was that in the user table I had a JSonObject as a field.
This mean that when you fetch a row from that table, and that row doesn't match your user, if you get the JSonObject field, Parse marsk that row as dirty, and so tries to save it again. Since that row doesn't match the ParseUser which you logged in, this throws the exception.
Moral of the story: in the User table don't use JSonObjects if this Objects have to be read by other users.

Answer (score 0):

From official [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-security)

**Security For User Objects**

The ParseUser class is secured by default. Data stored in a `ParseUser` can only be modified by that user. By default, the data can still be read by any client. Thus, some `ParseUser` objects are authenticated and can be modified, whereas others are read-only.

Specifically, you are not able to invoke any of the save or delete type methods unless the `ParseUser` was obtained using an authenticated method, like `logIn` or `signUp`. This ensures that only the user can alter their own data.

The following illustrates this security policy:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.logIn("my_username", "my_password");
user.setUsername("my_new_username"); // attempt to change username
user.saveInBackground(); // This succeeds, since the user was authenticated on the device

// Get the user from a non-authenticated manner
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground(user.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
    object.setUsername("another_username");

    // This will throw an exception, since the ParseUser is not authenticated
    object.saveInBackground();
  }
});
```

The `ParseUser` obtained from `getCurrentUser()` will always be authenticated.

If you need to check if a `ParseUser` is authenticated, you can invoke the `isAuthenticated()` method. You do not need to check `isAuthenticated()` with `ParseUser` objects that are obtained via an authenticated method.

Comment: But i'm not trying to edit a row in _User, but a row in another Table, where _User is just a type of a column and that user is even got by getCurrentUser().. so???

Comment: Please provide full real code, which gains exception. It's hard to determine what you did wrong by your pseudo code or part of it.